# Database has reached an unsafe level of usage

Tags: nodeos

I am getting "Database has reached an unsafe level of usage, shutting down to avoid corrupting the database.  Please increase the value set for "chain-state-db-size-mb" and restart the process!" error.

My "chain-state-db-size-mb = 65536".

Any other way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on localnet/testnet/mainnet you can increase your state db size by going through in your config.ini file and find chain-state-db-size-mb = 65536 and increase these numbers as per your requirement. You are getting this error because you have defined in you config.ini file size and that is 65536 So, now chain state is reached to this limit that's why you getting this error,hope it will work for you.